# Js function for check date

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this code. It should be able to insert into a form a range of dates from the current date up to a maximum of 90 days before, or any range between this period *(for example from 10/07/2023 to 20/07/2023... always remaining in the range of 90 days from today's date)*.
I cannot figure out why this code doesn't work and it allows me to insert even dates greater than the current date.

```
function solveDate1(input) {
    var value = input.value;
    var errorMessage = "";

    function formatDate(date) {
        var day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    }

    if (value !== "") {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var minDateFrom = new Date();
        minDateFrom.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 90); // 90 giorni fa
        var transactionDateFromInput = input.form.elements['dynaBean.TRANSACTIONDATEFROM'];
        var transactionDateToInput = input.form.elements['dynaBean.TRANSACTIONDATETO'];
        var selectedFromDate = new Date(transactionDateFromInput.value);
        var selectedToDate = new Date(transactionDateToInput.value);

        if (input.name === 'dynaBean.TRANSACTIONDATEFROM') {
            if (selectedFromDate < minDateFrom || selectedFromDate >= currentDate || selectedFromDate > selectedToDate) {
                var minDateFormatted = formatDate(minDateFrom);
                var maxDateFormatted = formatDate(currentDate);
                errorMessage = "Inserire una data valida tra " + minDateFormatted + " e " + maxDateFormatted;
            } else {
                transactionDateToInput.min = selectedFromDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                transactionDateToInput.value = ""; // Resetta il valore del campo TRANSACTIONDATETO
            }
        }

        if (input.name === 'dynaBean.TRANSACTIONDATETO') {
            if (selectedToDate > currentDate || selectedToDate < selectedFromDate || selectedToDate < minDateFrom) {
                var maxDateFormatted = formatDate(currentDate);
                errorMessage = "Inserire una data valida tra " + formatDate(minDateFrom) + " e " + maxDateFormatted + ", successiva alla data iniziale.";
            } else {
                transactionDateFromInput.max = selectedToDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
            }
        }

        // Mostra l'eventuale messaggio di errore con alert
        if (errorMessage !== "") {
            alert(errorMessage);
            input.value = ""; // Resetta il valore errato
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76930622/edit) and add the relevant HTML so we can actually interact with the function you wrote.

Comment: Have you checked in the browser debugger (or with `console.log()` calls) what the values of your input field dates are?

Comment: i didn't debug...will try now thanks

Comment: What format are users enering the date into the input? `new Date()` is not a general purpose date parser.

Comment: the format is dd/mm/yyyy